# C#: Access dynamic controls after Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm still new working with .NET and I'm still a bit confused about working with it's life cycle, which I think I need to work with to solve this problem.

I'll be adding a simplified version of the code, where I have to create a number of checkboxes using the strings contained in a List. Once they're created I should be able to select some of them, click another button, and get the number of selected checkboxes.

Due to the reload of the page, the Control values of dynamic content are removed, so it's not working. I tried using something like this:

```
ViewState.Add("panelCheckListContainer", CheckListContainer);
```

But I only get errors from that. I've seen some similar questions, but their solutions haven't worked for me or I haven't been able to make them work.

The code is the following:

```
Panel panelCheckListContainer = new Panel();

protected void buttonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> results = Get_Rand_Values();
    Get_CheckList(results);
}


private void Get_CheckList(List<string> results)
{
    CheckBox checkBox;
    panelCheckListContainer.ID = "correction-check-list";
    panelCheckListContainer.CssClass = "checkbox";

    foreach (string result in results)
    {

        checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.ID = Cypher_MD5(result);
        checkBox.Text = result;
        //checkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Change);

        panelCheckListContainer.Controls.Add(checkBox);

    }

    checkList.Controls.Add(panelCheckListContainer);
}


protected void buttonCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Control c in panelCheckListContainer.Controls)
    {
        if ((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Checked: " + i + "');</script>");
}
```

This is the placeholder where the checkboxes are attached:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="checkList"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As We know HTTP is a stateless protocol and ASP.NET goes through entire page life cycle for each request. Due to which it initialize a new page object with the initial controls. As dynamic control is not present in class definition and they instantiated at run time, because of this all dynamic controls remove from rendering. If someone want to render and load those dynamic control next time at page rendering then he should take care of the (dynamic control initialization ) code at page_load event.

Now you want to keep value of the dynamic control then you can use either "Request" object or "hidden field". I have add some code in your code snippet try this.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> results = Get_Rand_Values();
        Get_CheckList(results);
        Session["results"] = results;
    }
  protected void buttonCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //foreach (Control c in )
        //{
        //    if ((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
        //    {
        //        ++i;
        //    }
        //}
        var results = (List<string>)Session["results"];
        foreach (var k in results)
        {
            var tmp = Request[Cypher_MD5(k)];
            if(tmp  == "on")
            {
                i++;
            }
            count++;
        }
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Checked: " + i + "');</script>");
    }
```